# Passing class as function parameter

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have a class:

```
class MakeMeshStructure : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

MakeMeshStructure(QObject* parent = 0) {}
```

inside one of its functions I do this:

```
CadPanel * paneli;
int npanelov = mesh.faces_end().handle().idx();
paneli = new CadPanel[npanelov];
```

and later this:

```
for(int i=0; i<npanelov;i++){
    if(paneli[i].wasSet)paneli[i].draw(this);
}
```

this is my panel class:

```
class CadPanel : public QObject
{

Q_OBJECT
public:

CadPanel();
void draw(MakeMeshStructure* parent); //error here
```

The error is: Error 27  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MakeMeshStructure'

How do I pass MakeMeshStructure parent on to be used in this CadPanel function? Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add a forwarding class declaration to your class:

```
class MakeMeshStructure; // IMPORTANT: Declares a forwarding class

class CadPanel : public QObject 
{

    Q_OBJECT
public:

    CadPanel();
    void draw(MakeMeshStructure* parent); // no more error :)
}
```

Note that if the classes are in separate namespaces, you must qualify the name with the proper namespace.

Comment: Works! I added class MakeMeshStructure; in both hh and cc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use you do of MakeMeshStructure in CadPanel::draw() you may need to include the header containing the definition of MakeMeshStructure:

```
#include "MakeMeshStructure.h"
```

or simply make a forward declaration before the definition of CadPanel:

```
class MakeMeshStructure;
class CadPanel : public QObject
{
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is because when `MakeMeshStructure` is being compiled the compiler has no knowledge of the `CadPanel` class.

Since the `MakeMeshStructure` method is only using a pointer to `CadPanel` this problem can be solved using a forward declaration of `CadPanel`

```
class MakeMeshStructure; // Forward declaration of MakeMeshStructure

class CadPanel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CadPanel();
    void draw( MakeMeshStructure* parent );
};
```

However, if the `MakeMeshStructure` method created an instance of `CadPanel` you would be required to include the header within which `CadPanel` had been defined. This is because in order to create an instance of `CadPanel` the complete definition of the class is required.